# Override Typescript declaration type to declare static method on the Event class from the DOM

Tags: javascript, typescript

In a web application written in Javascript, I allowed myself to "enhance" the `Event` "class" from the DOM by adding a "static method" (I'm using quotes because it is a very approximate description) using following code:

```
Event.stop = function(event) {
    if(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

This works well. Here is an example:

```
document.getElementById('xxx').addEventListener('click', event => Event.stop(event));
```

Visual Studio Code is my favorite editor and I'm extensively using the embedded Typescript type checker. It flags the example above with the following error:

```
Property 'stop' does not exist on type '{ new (typeArg: string, eventInitDict?: EventInit): Event; prototype: Event; readonly AT_TARGET: ...'.
```

This is perfectly correct as there is no "stop" property on `Event` in vanilla Javascript.

Then, I created a custom Typescript type declaration file `xxx.d.ts` to declare this "stop" property to Typescript.

I tried following approaches but none of them is working:

```
interface EventConstructor {
    stop(event: Event);
}
```

or:

```
interface Event {
    stop(event: Event);
    static stop(event: Event);
}
```

and even:

```
var Event: {
    stop(event: Event);
};
```

What is the correct way to declare the "stop" function to Typescript?

For information, here is the declaration of `Event` from `lib.dom.d.ts`:

```
interface Event {
    readonly bubbles: boolean;
    cancelBubble: boolean;
    readonly cancelable: boolean;
    readonly composed: boolean;
    readonly currentTarget: EventTarget | null;
    readonly defaultPrevented: boolean;
    readonly eventPhase: number;
    readonly isTrusted: boolean;
    returnValue: boolean;
    readonly srcElement: Element | null;
    readonly target: EventTarget | null;
    readonly timeStamp: number;
    readonly type: string;
    deepPath(): EventTarget[];
    initEvent(type: string, bubbles?: boolean, cancelable?: boolean): void;
    preventDefault(): void;
    stopImmediatePropagation(): void;
    stopPropagation(): void;
    readonly AT_TARGET: number;
    readonly BUBBLING_PHASE: number;
    readonly CAPTURING_PHASE: number;
    readonly NONE: number;
}
declare var Event: {
    prototype: Event;
    new(typeArg: string, eventInitDict?: EventInit): Event;
    readonly AT_TARGET: number;
    readonly BUBBLING_PHASE: number;
    readonly CAPTURING_PHASE: number;
    readonly NONE: number;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this based on how the current definition of `Event` looks.

We can do this for `Array` for example because `Array` is declared as a variable of type `ArrayContructor`.

```
interface ArrayConstructor {
    ...
}

declare const Array: ArrayConstructor;
```

So when we want to add static methods to array we can leverage the merging behavior of interfaces. Since `ArrayConstructor` is an interface we can just redeclare it an add extra members and typescript will merge the two declaration of `ArrayConstructor` changing the efective type of `Array`

For `Event` the type of the variable is declared inline, we can't use the same approach because there is no interface to merge, and we can't merge a variable's type:

```
declare var Event: {
    prototype: Event;
    new(typeArg: string, eventInitDict?: EventInit): Event;
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've successfully overridden `ObjectConstructor`, and `FunctionConstructor` interfaces. The question is: why didn't they choose the same approach for DOM classes? Why is there no explicit `EventConstructor`? Is it a deliberated choice or a shortcut?

Comment: Yeah, I can't tell you 100%. My suspicion is that since there are differences between `es` versions with regard to the static methods on `Object`, `Function` and `Array` the typescript team needed to extends those types so they changed the definition to allow this. Probably the statics on `Event` have not changed so there was no need. But I am just speculating.

Comment: After a quick check, they did the `XXXConstructor` trick for a lot of standard Javascript classes (in `lib.d.ts`) but never for DOM classes (in `lib.dom.d.ts`). Maybe that's because exposure of DOM classes is not guaranteed (even if all modern browsers are doing it) and you're not supposed to interfere with them.